# Updating mongod configuration without restarting the service

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to reconfigure mongod without service disruption? Specifically, I'd like to change the `quiet` option without a restart.

I've tried sending SIGUSR1 (rotates log files) and SIGHUP to the process after updating the config file, but did not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

When I initially looked up the options on the mongodb.com site, I was reading up on the configuration file options.  However, the parameter reference guide at https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/parameters/ gives an example of how to update this config:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin")
db.runCommand( { setParameter: 1, quiet: 1 } )
```